# SOAP WS-Security Header not created when Axis2 Web Service is invoked from OSGi Client

Tags: osgi, apache-axis, rampart

We are using Axis2 and Rampart for SOAP web services. When a normal client invokes the stub, the SOAP message is properly created ( with WS-Security headers ) and serviced at the server. When we wrap the client ( along with the WS Stub and dependencies ) in a bundle and execute under OSGi ( Felix Karaf ) the header is not generated and this results in the Server returning a SoapFault.

The things that I have tried are

- Confirmed that the mar file is being accessed and rampart is "engage"d in OSGi
- Confirmed the version of all the jars being used
- Checked the SOAP message that is sent - noticed two differences

  - the message from the standard client had the namespaces declared and abbreviated while the OSGI version had the namespaces in every node
  - the OSGI message did not have the WS-Security Header

I have used a composite OSGI bundle which includes all the dependent non-OSGI jar files within the one bundle.

- Edit 1 - after further investigation through the axis2 / rampart code

I debugged the code side by side within OSGI and directly on JVM and noticed that the point of divergence is where axis engine while loading the "Security" handler invokes rampart and rampart goes with the default policy file instead of the mar file that was specified in "axis.repo.path". I was then looking at the loading of the policy by rampart - noticed it was not loading the configured policy but could not identify the issue.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Regards
Hari

Answer (score 0):

I guess that ws-security is implemented using some kind of plugin mechanism in Axis. Probably this mechanism is not working in OSGi.

I suggest to try CXF instead. It works very well in OSGi.

Comment: Thanks Christian for the suggestion. Unfortunately that option is not feasible in the current context as I am just building a client to an existing Axis WebService.